# Stream A Video file and Block Direct Download.

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, streaming, hide

I Want to Stream a file (mp4) with a flash player, but i want to hide or block the direct link..i've tryed many things but none of these worked, so i'm asking if is possible do this..thanks you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server can run it, then your client can extract the video too. There are several tools for that. You could separate the file in different parts or use different obfuscation technologies, but that would, as said, serve no point, except for stopping some manual downloading.

Summary: **If client can view it, he can also download it**.

Update:
You could, however, make it harder by using something like `getVideo.php?id=1` as URL where you check if the script is being ran directly to ensure that the user isn't visiting the page (and therefore trying to access the video source) directly.

In your page that should be run:

```
define('APP', 'MyApplication');
```

And in the getVideo.php:

```
if(!defined('APP')){ 
  die("No direct access is allowed.");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but would be good also just hide the link trough a php page for make it harder for the user to direct download the video, However Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: You're welcome :-). Updated my answer with an approach that might add some security.

Comment: Thanks You, i try your updated answer! and i let you know! :) thanks again. ;)